# What is a word for "a person who studies all subjects"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think it should be "philosopher", but I am not sure.

Does philosophy encompass all subject matter?

Is there a word that describes someone who studies all subjects?

So, if a scientist studies science, and a theologian studies religion, is there a word for someone who studies both?

A sample sentence might be:

> The '_____' is constantly learning, because the universe is infinite.

Here is an analogy:

> Science is to Scientist as Everything is to '_____'.

Edit:

The word is likely to end with -ist or -er. The word should describe a person who specifically studies everything. My made up word would be: "everythingologist".

Comment: Philomath, polymath, pansophist, etc.

Comment: A less formal and precise equivalent of "polymath" is "renaissance man" (or woman).

Comment: I am looking for a word that means "someone who studies everything". This person would likely ALSO be a philomath, polymath, pansophist, and a reaissance man. This word would likely end with -ist, or -er. Thank you for the edit, that looks better.

Comment: A *polymath* is someone who studies and is an expert in a vast range of topics.  No one is capable of studying *all* topics.

Comment: Ok, so maybe there is not a specific word, but the suggestions here have given me some more options, thank you.

Comment: What @vickyace said. There is also *dilettante*, which is a less serious studier of lots of things: wide but typically not deep study/interest.

Comment: I’m thinking ***overambitious*** or ***drastically oversubscribed***... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny you should ask that.

***Philosophy*** meant "love of wisdom" in the original Greek. It encompassed many entities that today are viewed as separate disciplines. Certainly the famous line from William Shakespeare's *Hamlet* would indicate that back in Shakespeare's time philosophy still included natural sciences, though not necessarily art and literature:

> There are more things in heav'n and earth, Horatio,
>   Than are dreamed of in your *philosophy*.

Later on, fields besides natural sciences became separate disciplines, such as theology and philosophy in the modern sense of the word.

I'm afraid there is no precise word that would describe a person who actually studies (i.e. has a working familiarity with) every possible discipline out there.

a **pansophist**

is a person who *claims or pretends* to have studied everything

a **polymath**

is someone who is versed in more than one, though *not* necessarily all, disciplines.

Comment: polymath is the correct idiomatic term .  you could also go with "Rennaissance man" (sp?)

Comment: These suggestions are close, and I learned something. It appears a word with the exact meaning I am looking for may not exist. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe, simply, scientist? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_science

Comment: Or interdisciplinarian? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interdisciplinarian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdisciplinarity

Comment: Upvoting for "polymath," that seems like the answer here.